# Complex integral of the modulus of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-integration

In Rudin's *Functional Analysis* book there is this exercise (Chapter 8, Exercise 1b):

> Let $P$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Prove that if
>   $$
> \int_{T^n} |P| = 0,
> $$
>   where $T^n$ is the torus in $\mathbb{C}^n$: $T^n = \{(e^{i t_1},\dots,e^{i t_n})\colon t_i \in \mathbb{R},\ i = 1,\dots,n\}$, then $P$ is identically $0$. (Hint: Compute $\int_{T^n} |P|^2$).

There is something that I don't understand here. Let $n = 1$ and $P(z) = 1$. Then $\int_{T^1} |P| = 0$, however $P \neq 0$. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I think I know where is my mistake. The integral $\int_{T^1} |P|$ is not complex integral, but rather (is it right?)
$$
\int_{T^1} |P| = (2\pi)^{-1} \int_0^{2\pi} |P(e^{i t})| dt.
$$
Then, however, what's the point of the exercise? If the above definition is correct, then |P| is non-negative and hence $\int_{T^1} |P| = 0$ if and only if $P = 0$.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Just to be 100% clear is $P$ a polynomial in one variable or more?

Comment: I just see two ways you could state this $P \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots x_n]$ or $P \in \mathbb{C}^n[X]$

Comment: As far as I understand if $n=1$, then $P$ is a complex polynomial in one (complex) variable. If $n > 1$ then $P(z) = \sum c_\alpha z^\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a multi-index and $z \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: So both coefficients $c_\alpha$ are vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and and you have multiple variables $z^\alpha=\prod x_i^{\alpha_i}$?

Comment: @N8tron $c_\alpha$ is complex number and $z^\alpha = \prod z_i^{\alpha_i}$, where $z_i \in \mathbb{C}$. But even in the case $n=1$ I don't understand what is going on. It seems to me that the exercise is trivial because we basically integrate nonnegative function, hence the integral should be zero if and only if the function is zero.

Comment: Okay so $P \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ where $X=[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$. Then $L^2(T^n)$ is a hilbert space so   $|P|^2=\overline{P}P$ and $\left\|P\right\|^2=<P,P>=\int_{T^n} \overline{P}P =0$ implies $P=0$  if $P \in L^2(T^n)$.

Comment: @N8tron And why $\int_{T^n} \bar P P = 0$?

Comment: You're correct, you'd have to show if $\int |P| =0$ then $\int |P|^2 =0$